# What is the difference between Больше and ещё

Tags: выбор-слова

I am confused; don't both of these words mean "more"? What is the literal meaning and context of each? Sample sentences would be helpful! спасибо!

Comment: "Больше" actually means "more". About the word "ещё" see this topic - http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/9075/the-meaning-of-%D0%95%D1%89%D1%91

Answer (score 1):

I'd say *ещё* implies a continuing process, like putting food on a dish or enumerating objects, in positive sentences, while *больше* is used in negative sentences and when discussing sizes.

Ещё мне добавь - Give me more (money, food)

Больше не надо - Don't need more (goes with anything)

А ещё больше есть? - Do you have an even bigger one (shirt, car)?

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide context of usage of word "more"?

Больше can has meaning "Bigger", but "Ещё" can`t
Ex:
Красная чашка больше зеленой.

I suppose it`s better to use "ещё" as translation for word "more", but it can be context-dependent.